# Unable to resolve overflow of text in angular4 and html

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a very large text and I am using a table to display the text. However, the text overflows. I have used all the attributes in text-overflow be it -

```
{ text-overflow: clip; }

{ text-overflow: ellipsis; }

{ text-overflow: ellipsis-word; }

{ text-overflow: "---"; }

{ text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis; text-align: center; }
```

or be it -

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

And when I use slice in my component.html, the tooltip  doesn't appear. So I am not using it as the tooltip is important.

Please suggest a few changes in the css.

[Overflown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8eKq.png)

**component.css**

```
 #addbtn{
 float:right;
  }
 thead>tr>th:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #384c57;
 color: rgb(240, 202, 132);
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 
 0.24);
 }
th{
width:1px;white-space:nowrap;
}

table{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

thead{
background-color: #33444d;
color: white;
 }


.card{
border: none !important;
 }


#faIcon{
background: #2f4855;
color: white;
border: none;
 }

input:hover {
background-color: rgb(247, 185, 114)  
 }

 input:focus{
 border : 2px solid rgb(247, 185, 114) !important;
 }

 .panel {
 border: none;
 margin-bottom: 0
  }

.panel-transparent {
 background: none;
 }

td{
height:10px;
}

.zoom {
 padding: 50px;

 transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */

 margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .zoom:hover {
transform: scale(3.0); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, 
 it will go outside of the viewport) */
}


.table{
 color:rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color:rgba(17, 26, 24, 0.452);
 }

.panel-transparent .panel-heading{
background: rgba(44, 51, 59, 0.575)!important;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;

}

.my-pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination .current {
background: #33444d;

 }

 #close{
 color:#708e9e;
 }

#close:hover{
color: white;
size: 25px;
}

#payloadData{
// border-image-slice: 10%;
 width:15px;
// word-break: break-all;

// box-decoration-break: slice;
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis ellipsis; text-align: center;
direction:ltr;
word-break: break-all;
//  text-overflow: ellipsis;
// text-overflow: ellipsis-word;
 }
```

**component.html**

```
   <td  title="{{dat.PAYLOAD}}" id="payloadData"> 
  {{dat.PAYLOAD}}</td>
```

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` should be used along with `overflow: hidden`, did you do that?

Comment: I don't see any images in your questions

Comment: vikram now you can see.... thank you

Comment: @Jeremy Thille ... yes i am using it. Please check in #payload data

Comment: Try this: #payloadData{width:15px; text-align: center;}

Comment: @skm ..thank you .. but i solved the issue... i simply interchanged the table columns and also using a slice. It worked. The tooltip was just not getting enough space to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` use `word-break: break-word;`
and provide max-height to outer div and keep `overflow-y:auto`. this may help you